# Mirror/inherit a module for outputting some fields of the original

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible, in Django, to create a module which is linked via a OneToOneField to another one, which only outputs a single field of its parent?

Something like:

```
class Venue(models.Model): # this is the parent
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    venue_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    venue_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class VenueCity(models.Model): # should this be (Venue)?
    venue_city = # this is the OneToOneField linked to the venue_city field of the parent
```

I need this because it'd be very handy for using it with a select2 field (
[django_select2 - limit the returned text to a specific field in module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699422/django-select2-limit-the-returned-text-to-a-specific-field-in-module)) and I cannot use a `@property`, only a proper module.

** Addition: widget code **

```
class VenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = ['venue_name', 'venue_city', 'venue_country']

        widgets = {
            'venue_city': s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget(model=Venue,
             search_fields=['venue_city__icontains'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not as such. You could probably use Django-select2's [label override function](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.ModelSelect2Mixin.label_from_instance) to show only the city name from the venue model, and maybe override the queryset too if you want uniquely cities only.

Comment: Thank you @AKX, I was looking into it right now, it looks promising. Unfortunately the documentation doesn't explain how to apply it in practice, where would I put that label_from_instance? I'm using class Meta [...] widgets = {'venue_city' s2forms.Select2Widget etc...'. label_from_instance(obj) = obj.venue_city returns a "positional argument follows keyword argument" error.

Comment: Add your new code in your post, it's hard to decipher from a comment.